# Piwik tracking API returns GIF89

Tags: php, matomo

I guess I'm missing something basic here, but when I try out the example from [here](https://piwik.org/docs/tracking-api/) (adapted to my context):

```
<?php 
$piwikTracker = new PiwikTracker( $idSite = {$IDSITE} );

// Specify an API token with at least Admin permission, so the Visitor IP address can be recorded 
// Learn more about token_auth: https://piwik.org/faq/general/faq_114/
$piwikTracker->setTokenAuth('my_token_auth_value_here');

// You can manually set the visitor details (resolution, time, plugins, etc.) 
// See all other ->set* functions available in the PiwikTracker.php file
$piwikTracker->setResolution(1600, 1400);

// Sends Tracker request via http
$piwikTracker->doTrackPageView('Document title of current page view');

// You can also track Goal conversions
$result = $piwikTracker->doTrackGoal($idGoal = 1, $revenue = 42);
?>
```

the `$result` variable contains

```
GIF89a�����������!�����,�������D�;
```

which I'm told is a small tracking GIF. But why on earth would the API return a tracking GIF? Shouldn't it rather be a status result about success/failure?

Comment: Judging by the examples you're not supposed to make use of the return value when the API is called this way. Anyway this should evaluate to true if tested.

Comment: @Calimero That is pretty lousy API design. Since the API requires a token for validation, I need to know if the request was successful or not. I get the same result even if I set auth token to mumbo jumbo.

Comment: Maybe consider contributing a better design then, as piwik is an open-source project, that might be just the right thing to do.